# Copy rows matching two criteria into another sheet and then delete original rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was kindly pointed in the right direction for the following code written by The Master, and am wondering how I could change it so that for N:N rows, AND also for those same rows to be checked against a third critera, where column I:I is ALSO less than or equal to Today()-60? I have added DueDateRange and DueDateValues (for column I, which will be the condition check), but don't know how to ensure that the rows selected meet both N:N AND I:I criteria suggested.

As it stands right now, the N:N check works perfectly well, but I need it to only take those matching rows that also have the due date criteria.

Any help greatly appreciated:

```js
function CopyRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking Data'); //source sheet
  var StatusRange = sheet.getRange('N:N'); //Status column
  var DueDateRange = sheet.getRange("I:I"); //DueDate column
  var StatusValue = (StatusRange.getValues());
  var DueDateValue = (DueDateRange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Historical'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

  //Condition check in N:N; If true copy the same row to data array
for (i=0; i<StatusValue.length;i++) {
  if ( StatusValue[i] == 'Returned' || StatusValue[i] == 'RUD' ) {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,17).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
//Copy data array to destination sheet

 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

//Delete matched rows in source sheet
  for (i=0;i<j.length;i++){
  var k = j[i]+1;
  sheet.deleteRow(k);

//Alter j to account for deleted rows
  if (!(i == j.length-1)) {
  j[i+1] = j[i+1]-i-1;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function CopyRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking Data'); //source sheet
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 60).valueOf();
  var StatusRange = sh.getRange('N1:N' + sh.getLastRow()); //Status column
  var DueDateRange = sh.getRange("I1:I" + sh.getLastRow()); //DueDate column
  var StatusValue = StatusRange.getValues().flat();
  var DueDateValue = DueDateRange.getValues().flat();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Historical'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j = [];
  for (i = 0; i < StatusValue.length; i++) {
    if (new Date(DueDateValue[i]).valueOf() < dtv) {
      if (StatusValue[i] == 'Returned' || StatusValue[i] == 'RUD') {
        data.push.apply(data, sh.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 17).getValues());
        //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
        j.push(i);
      }
    }
  }
  //Copy data array to destination sheet

  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

  //Delete matched rows in source sheet
  for (i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    var k = j[i] + 1;
    sh.deleteRow(k);

    //Alter j to account for deleted rows
    if (!(i == j.length - 1)) {
      j[i + 1] = j[i + 1] - i - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic and works perfectly well. Thank you so much. 
Q: Is it safe to run this on a timer event rather than manually? Are there any risks I should be aware of? Is there a way to add a snippet of code to this function that will email me to tell me it has been successful (or not)?